# tar exclude parameter with single quote in ksh

Tags: bash, ksh, tar, quote

I have a problem with the following ksh script:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh 

EXCLUDE+=" --exclude '/bin/a*' "
echo $EXCLUDE
tar --preserve-permissions --create  $EXCLUDE --file tar.tar /bin
```

Since passing in a pattern to the exclude target need single quotes around it. (I want to exclude all files in /bin folder beginning with "a").

The Echo line also show the correct and unchanged result (the pattern didn't expand and the single quote is still there). However this exclude target has no effect.

But if I put the actual value instead of $EXCLUDE, it worked!

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh 

tar --preserve-permissions --create  --exclude '/bin/a*' --file tar.tar /bin
```

It must be some quoting issue I'm encountering, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXCLUDE=' --exclude /bin/a* '` is enough.
Your code excludes the `'/bin/a*'` (quotes`''` are part of pattern) pattern but what you actually want is to exclude `/bin/a*` pattern.

Comment: @user892960: you wanted to exclude `/bin/a*` pattern,not `'/bin/a*'`. (quotes are part of pattern)

Comment: I have tested your proposal and it get some unexpected behavior: According to [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/problems-with-exclude.html#SEC109) the pattern must be surrounded bu `''` otherwise it will be expanded and I will get unwanted result: `--exclude [filename1] [filename2]...` and then the tar command become illegal (this is correct: `--exclude [filename1] --exclude [filename2]...`).

Comment: @user892960: unexpected behavior?. the whole string in the variable `EXCLUDE` is enclosed with single quotes which preserves the literal value. Did you try Jonathan's `al` tool or -x option? it would have shown you that the literal value of wildcard(`*`) is preserved.

Comment: Yes I tried with Jonathan's `al` and got following output with your proposal: `tar --preserve-permissions --create --exclude /bin/arch /bin/ash /bin/ash.static /bin/awk --file tar.tar /bin` which is an illegal tar command. But if I put `set -f` before the tar command it worked. In fact, if I use double quotes around the exclude string it also worked when I put `set -f` before the tar command. So the problem for me is whether or not the globbing is disabled, regardless of single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: Have you really tested it? The other guy which stated that your proposal should work has also changed saying that `set -f` is the way to make it work, after he did the test.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

Yes, your problem is related to quoting.

#### Discussion

When debugging this sort of issue, I find that a variant of `echo` that prints its arguments one per line is invaluable.  The name I use for it is `al` (for 'argument list').  With that used as a prefix to the `tar` command in your script, run using '`ksh -x tartest.ksh`', the trace output is:

```
+ EXCLUDE+=$' --exclude \'/bin/a*\' '
+ echo --exclude $'\'/bin/a*\''
--exclude '/bin/a*'
+ al tar --preserve-permissions --create --exclude $'\'/bin/a*\'' --file tar.tar /bin
tar
--preserve-permissions
--create
--exclude
'/bin/a*'
--file
tar.tar
/bin
```

Note how the shell has gone to considerable lengths to ensure that the `tar` command (or the `al` command) sees the single quotes.  When you follow [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571189/john)'s advice, you see a different output:

```
+ EXCLUDE+=' --exclude /bin/a* '
+ echo --exclude '/bin/a*'
--exclude /bin/a*
+ al tar --preserve-permissions --create --exclude '/bin/a*' --file tar.tar /bin
tar
--preserve-permissions
--create
--exclude
/bin/a*
--file
tar.tar
/bin
```

Note that this time, `tar` (`al`) sees exactly `/bin/a*` and not `'/bin/a*'`.

---

You can write `al` trivially in C or shell:

```
for arg; do echo "$arg"; done

#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv != 0)
        puts(*argv);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Testing performed on MacOS X 10.7 with `/bin/ksh`, which identifies itself as:

```
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 1993-12-28 s+
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know how this al command can help me fix this issue, according to [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC109) a quote is needed when passing in a pattern. in the script I cannot hardcode the exclude parameter with the pattern, I must pass it in as a variable.

Comment: @user892960: the `al` command helps you to see exactly what arguments your 'real' command (`tar`) is seeing. It can be especially helpful when arguments contain spaces, and you find that your command is not getting the arguments you expected - as in this case where the `tar` command was being given arguments with the single quotes still present, which is why the `--exclude` option did not do what you expected. Now you can see why; none of the file names included the single quotes that the shell relayed to `tar`.  [..continued...]

Comment: [...continued...] The `al` command is a debugging tool; it helps you see what the command you are trying to debug sees as the argument list. (It can still be mildly confusing if your arguments contain newlines, but it is typically easier to understand than the output from `echo` in such circumstances.)

Comment: OK thanks, I got it. but having this tool will show what is wrong, but how do I know the right answer?

Comment: @user892960: Ah...well, then you have to read the manual again (and again, and maybe again), and experiment.  And I find the `al` command useful when experimenting, along with the `-x` flag.  Ultimately, it comes down to knowing your tool (the shell in this case), and practice and reading are the best ways to learn it.  There isn't a magic bullet - unless you count asking questions on StackOverflow as a magic bullet.

Comment: @user892960: Since the file `/bin/a*` matches the pattern `/bin/a*`, you cannot do it like that.  You have to get inventive.  For example, you could use `/bin/[a]*` to match file names starting with a letter `a`.  However, having a program called `a*` is pretty unusual - even obnoxious.  I'll assume you've picked on `/bin` to disguise your real requirement, but having file names containing metacharacters leads to trouble.  And remember, from one viewpoint, spaces are metacharacters to the shell; they separate arguments.  So spaces in filenames are apt to cause trouble.

Comment: OK thanks anyhow. I thought this issue is quote common so I can get a quick answer here.

Comment: `/bin/a*` is just a bad example, the real example is `[someDir]/*.[someExtentionToExclude]`